# SSL Certificate for Wordpress instance created using EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I want to add SSL certificate using AWS Certificate Manager for my website which I created using a Wordpress instance on EC2, hosted the domain with Route 53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately a public ACM certificate can not be deployed to your individual EC2 host. It must be attached to one of the following options:

- [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)
- [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)

If you are able to put your instance behind one of these you'll be able to use your ACM certificate.

Outside of that ACM does support [private CAs](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/private-certificate-authority/) that can be deployed to resources but they do cost $400 per month for each CA.

Alternatively if you want to have a free SSL, using **only an EC2 instance** I would suggest looking at [certbot].

AWS has created a tutorial for setting it up [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html).

Comment: Thanks I just used the one with Cloudflare to link it to my website.